# problem in numerical updown in c#

Tags: c#, .net

i am using numerical updown in my form,

there if i change the value itself a event should raise,
(eg:if i change the value from 6 to 7 in the numerical updown a event should raise)
i used ValueChange event for that, but that event is getting raised, only if the value is changing on mousewheel or on spinbutton.
if i enter the value on the numerical updown with keyboard,
that event is not raising.

Comment: stian thanks for telling me about that... now only i came to know about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `KeyPress` event.

Comment: i tried that, it s not working,
because,
if i press a key it wont trigger, when i press the next key only the
event for previous key will trigger

Answer (score 2):

according to MSDN:

> For the ValueChanged event to occur,
>   the Value property can be changed in
>   code, by clicking the up or down
>   button, or by the user entering a new
>   value that is read by the control. The
>   new value is read when the user hits
>   the ENTER key or navigates away from
>   the control. If the user enters a new
>   value and then clicks the up or down
>   button, the ValueChanged event will
>   occur twice.

Therefore the user needs to press Enter, if that's not an option use the KeyPress Event

Or [TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.numericupdown.textchanged%28VS.80%29.aspx) event, but there's a disclaimer

> This event supports the .NET Framework
>   infrastructure and is not intended to
>   be used directly from your code.

Comment: But without pressing that enter itself my event should raise.... this keypress is not effective i tried it...

Comment: Users are used to press Enter after entering something. It should be fine.